# Computing function offset differences

Tags: c, functions, offset

When I'm trying to compute the difference between two functions loaded into memory:

```
int _start(void)
{
    // code
}

int _end(void)
{
    // code
}

DWORD funcSize = (DWORD) _end - (DWORD) _start;
```

`funcSize` is computed incorrectly. For example, if the offset of `_start` is **0x00291450** and the offset of `_end` is **0x002915a0** the difference between `_end` and `_start` is **0xffffff56**. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Because end is greater than start and you see the actual representation of negative number. `(DWORD) _end - (DWORD) _start` should give you a more reasonable number.

Just for completeness sake: the computations with numbers you provided (may be checked in windows calculator or with python)

```
0x002915a0 - 0x00291450 = 0x150
0x00291450 - 0x002915a0 = -0x150 (0xfffffeb0)
```

The difference between numbers which ends with 0 can not end with non-zero like in number as you mentioned `(0xffffff56)`, so there is something wrong with your calculation.
UPD:
Just in case if you are using C language, you probably should use &_start and &_end instead of _start and _end.

Comment: Sorry I meant _end()  -  start() gives a negative number. Why does _end() have a smaller address than _start().

Comment: According to numbers you mentioned _end is greater than _start.

Comment: When I subtract the address of _start() from that of _end() the result is negative even though the address of _end() is greater than that of _start().

Comment: I updated the answer. Please review your calculation, something with the numbers and results is inconsistent.

Comment: And shouldn't you use &_end instead of _end and &_start instead of start correspondingly ?